# Optimizing personnel allocation within a fixed period

Tags: optimization, vehicle-routing, clustering

I am working on an operations optimization problem and am describing the problem below. At first glance, it seems like a mix of vehicle route optimization and a scheduling problem.

The expected solution will effectively allocate outlets for salespeople based on a combination of

1. Most optimized route
2. Other constraints based on outlet characteristics

Consider a salesperson, a single salesperson is associated with 200 outlets. They work 24 days a month.
At a monthly level, associated outlets must be assigned daily to the salesperson based on the optimized route (travelling salesman problem). This is straightforward if all the outlets must be visited only once.

However, there is a catch. Some of the outlets from the pool of 200 must be assigned multiple times for the month based on their priority (1-4 times), and the assignments should be equidistant from each other. e.g., if an outlet with priority two is assigned on day 1 of week 1, the outlet will need to be reassigned on day one of week three all the while ensuring the shortest route traveled.

I am looking for some direction to be able to address the above problem. Possible solutions, references, directions insights etc.

Comment: Maybe you can find something similar in the literature on *periodic vehicle routing problems*